# What bug tracking system is this, or is it Drupal?

Tags: drupal, issue-trackers

Can't figure out is this is Drupal, or some other bug tracking system:

http://drupal.org/project/issues/search/redesign?issue_tags=drupal.org+redesign+qa

Any ideas how to figure it out?

Also, in general how do you tell if a site, or part of a site is using Drupal?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, everything on the drupal.org domain is powered by Drupal. The issue tracker on drupal.org is built with a number of modules. I don't know the exact list, but some important ones are [Project](http://drupal.org/project/project), [Project Issue Tracking](http://drupal.org/project/project_issue) and [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).

If I want to know if a site is built with Drupal, I use http://isthissitebuiltwithdrupal.com. Click the 'Tell me more' link on that page to learn how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is a bug tracking system developed by Drupal. You could always send an email to the developers and find out. Usually if someone is using Drupal on their site it would say something like "Powered by Drupal" or what ever the developer puts there if anything. Other then that there is no way I know of to see if a site is using Drupal.